# Storing each operation of fold operation in List

Tags: scala

To sum using fold I use :

```
  val l = List(1, 2, 3)
  val sum = l.fold(0) { (a, b) => a + b }
```

How can I capture the result of each add operation in a list? So for above the following is stored :

```
List(0,1,3,6)
```

Only option I can think of is instead of fold iterate over the list and store the result of each operation in an mutable list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `scanLeft` does!

```
scala> val sum = l.scanLeft(0) { (a, b) => a + b }
sum: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3, 6)
```

It's exactly what you're looking for—a version of `fold` that holds on to the result of each operation.